# Simple lookup does not return correct values

Tags: microsoft-excel, lookup

I have a very simple situation:

```
Column I  Column J
S         0
M         1
X         2
XL        3
```

I would need the lookup to return number based on the size, which is entered in the cell D6:

```
=LOOKUP(D6;I:I;J:J)
```

It shows either wrong values or `N/A`. What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 6):

As per [the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) your values need to be sorted.

> Important: The values in lookup_vector must be placed in ascending order: ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ..., A-Z, FALSE, TRUE; otherwise, LOOKUP might not return the correct value. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent.

```
M   1
S   0
X   2
XL  3
```

Comment: Ah, I see, Alphabetically..I was ordering differently

Answer (score 1):

`LOOKUP` requires the list to be sorted in alphabetical order. However, if you do not want to sort the list, it is possible to use the `OFFSET` and `MATCH` functions instead.

```
=OFFSET(I1,MATCH(D6,I1:I4,0),1)
```

- `I1` is where the first list starts (S,M,X,XL)
- `D6` is the value you want to lookup
- `I1:I4` is the range of the first list
- The last 1 means that the value to return is one step to the left of the list to seach. Since htey are next to each other, the value is 1.